# remove a word from url and 301 redirect

Tags: regex, .htaccess, redirect

The actual link structure is as follows:

> domain.com/browse-wordtoremove-string.html

we want to 301 redirect to

> domain.com/browse-string.html

How can be his be achieved?

Thank you so much in advance.

Comment: is the url structure always same ? i.e. always with only 2 hiphens etc

Comment: It is just remove the word, everything else is the same on both url structures

Comment: in that case look below for my solution it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one to remove the word.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*?)-wordtoremove-(.*\.html)$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

Assuming its between the hyphen(`-`). If not then remove the hyphens from everywhere on above(three times).

Comment: @Sabuj what do those things in the square bracket stand for ?

Comment: @aelor These are flags. `[L]` means Last that forces to stop the rule after this one. and `[R]` is for `http redirect`. You can add status code with `[R]`. This [link](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html) will help you to understand the flag with more details.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule as your very first rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(browse-)[^-]+-([^.-]+\.html)$ /$1$2 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Answer (score 0):

demo here http://regex101.com/r/pS3pU4

search for this `\-.*?\-`

and replace with `-`

in javascript you can replace and redirect like this

```
var url = "domain.com/browse-wordtoremove-string.html";
var res = url.replace(/\-.*?\-/,'-');
location.href = res;
```